# df -h shows different size on nfs client than on nfs server

Tags: server, mount, configuration, nfs

I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS on two servers in AWS. One is running nfsd and the other is running the client. I made a 250GB EBS volume and shared it, then I went onto the client and mounted it.

Here's the server

```
ubuntu@nfs:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  954M  6.4G  13% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           377M  340K  377M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb       250G   33M  250G   1% /mnt/nfsstore
```

Here's the command I ran on the client

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 nfs.prod:/ /mnt
```

Here's the client

```
ubuntu@web11:~$ df -h
Filesystem    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1    7.8G  1.1G  6.3G  15% /
none          4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev          1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs         377M  348K  377M   1% /run
none          5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none          1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
none          100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb      20G   44M   19G   1% /var/www
nfs.prod:/    7.8G  954M  6.4G  13% /mnt
```

I was expecting 250G to be available at /mnt/nfsstore - is this a display bug, or can I expect only 6.4GB of space available?

Comment: Filesystems mounted in somewhere inside an exported directory needs to be exported separately.

Answer (score 1):

At first view, it seems that client `/mnt` = server `/` instead of `/mnt/nfsstore`, check `/etc/export` on the server (you should add its content to your question).
Try `sudo mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 nfs.prod:/mnt/nfsstore /mnt`, it should fix it.

Comment: cat /etc/exports gives `/export 172.31.0.0/24(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,sync)
/export/nfsstore 172.31.0.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,sync)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @cylgalad - this is what I did:

```
sudo umount /mnt
mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 nfs.prod:/export/nfsstore /mnt
```

Now:

```
df -h
...
nfs.prod:/export/nfsstore  250G   32M  250G   1% /mnt
```

Good to go. Thanks much!